# PHP - opendir on another server

Tags: php, directory, opendir

I'm kinda new to PHP.

I've got two different hosts and I want my php page in one of them to show me a directory listing of the other. I know how to work with opendir() on the same host but is it possible to use it to get access to another machine?

Thanks in advance

Comment: there are no abstract "servers"to connect to. you have to specify certain **protocol** which remote server supports and you going to use.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could use PHP's [FTP Capabilities](http://php.net/ftp) to remotely connect to the server and get a directory listing:

```
// set up basic connection
$conn_id = ftp_connect('otherserver.example.com'); 

// login with username and password
$login_result = ftp_login($conn_id, 'username', 'password'); 

// check connection
if ((!$conn_id) || (!$login_result)) { 
    echo "FTP connection has failed!";
    exit; 
}

// upload the file
$upload = ftp_put($conn_id, $destination_file, $source_file, FTP_BINARY); 

// check upload status
if (!$upload) { 
    echo "FTP upload has failed!";
} else {
    echo "Uploaded $source_file to $ftp_server as $destination_file";
}

// Retrieve directory listing
$files = ftp_nlist($conn_id, '/remote_dir');

// close the FTP stream 
ftp_close($conn_id);
```

Answer (score 7):

Try:

```
<?php

$dir = opendir('ftp://user:pass@domain.tld/path/to/dir/');

while (($file = readdir($dir)) !== false) {
    if ($file[0] != ".") $str .= "\t<li>$file</li>\n";
}

closedir($dir);

echo "<ul>\n$str</ul>";
```

Answer (score 0):

I was unable to get the FTP suggestions to work so I took a more unconventional route, basically it yanks the html from the "Index of" page and extracts the filenames.

*Index page:*

## Index of /files

[Parent Directory](/#)

[1.jpg](/#)

[2.jpg](/#)

*Extraction code:*

```
    $dir = "http://www.yoursite.com/files/";
    $contents = file_get_contents($dir);
    $lines = explode("\n", $contents);
    foreach($lines as $line) {
        if($line[1] == "l") { // matches the <li> tag and skips 'Parent Directory'
            $line = preg_replace('/<[^<]+?>/', '', $line); // removes tags, curtousy of http://stackoverflow.com/users/154877/marcel
            echo trim($line) . "\n";
        }
    }
```