# Can I use PHP opendir() on a external URL?

Tags: php, rackspace, opendir, akamai

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [PHP - opendir on another server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5292984/php-opendir-on-another-server)

Something like this:

`opendir(http://super.cdn.com/running_order_image/sale/587/)`

The `opendir` is being used to check the contents of a Rackspace Cloud Files Akamai bucket.

I am looping through a structure like this

```
587/
587/587_rubyred
587/587_rubyred/front.jpg
587/587_rubyred/back.jpg
```

I am trying to return the `587_rubyred` part. Basically my MySQL query loops through the 587 and 834 and other numbers, I then check the directory for those numbers and return the first subfolder.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to connect to rackspace cloud files, I'd suggest using the API located at https://github.com/rackspace/php-cloudfiles

```
$auth = new CF_Authentication('<RACKSPACELOGIN>','<RACKSPACEKEY>');
$auth->authenticate();
$conn = new CF_Connection($auth);
$cloudFolder = $conn->get_container('<RACKSPACECONTAINER>');    
$cloudImages = $cloudFolder->get_objects();

foreach($cloudImages as $image)
{
  echo '<li>' . $image->name . '</li>';
}
```

edit: you will then be able to perform the following

```
$cloudImages = $cloudFolder->get_objects(0,NULL,NULL,'587/587_rubyred');
```

Answer (score 3):

This is not possible. The most servers have the directory listing disabled and doesn't send a directory list opendir is for local directories.

[PHP - opendir on another server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5292984/php-opendir-on-another-server)

You can access over ftp or something else.

Answer (score 2):

No. There is no concept of a directory in URLs.

A URL might map on to a directory on the server's filesystem, but that mapping is not exposed by HTTP.

`http://example/running_order_image/sale/587/` might give you an HTML document with links to everything in a directory on the server, but you would have to access it like any other resource, then parse the HTML to get the URLs to those resources.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you look in the specs?

https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.opendir.php

Look under changelog:

4.3.0   path can also be any URL which supports directory listing, however only the file:// URL wrapper supports this in PHP 4

So if this works depends on the server you approaching. I know my servers won't allow it. ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Try to use [FTP](http://php.net/manual/en/book.ftp.php) in PHP. This will allow you to remotely connect to the server. Of course only if it is allowed to connect via FTP.